# Task to replace first and last character of two strings

Tags: c#

I am doing exercise which provides solutions too however, no explanation on the code in the solution is given and cannot understand the code. Hope I can get help in understanding it

**Exercise:**
Write a C# program to create a new string from a given string where the first and last characters will change their positions.

**Strings:**
w3resource
Python

**Expected output:**
e3resourcw
nythoP

**Solution:**

```
public class Exercise16 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first_last("w3resource"));
            Console.WriteLine(first_last("Python"));
            Console.WriteLine(first_last("x"));
        }
       public static string first_last(string ustr)
        {
          // code that I don't understand
           return ustr.Length > 1
           ? ustr.Substring(ustr.Length - 1) + ustr.Substring(1, ustr.Length - 2) + ustr.Substring(0, 1) : ustr;
            }
    }
```

P.S - I am beginner in C# but not in programming overall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` operator is also called the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) in C#. It acts like a miniature `if` statement letting you express the entire statement in a single expression. In this case it is used to verify that there is at least two characters in the string, otherwise it returns the single character string itself.

As for the `Substring` statements, consider which characters are being extracted from `ustr` with each call...

- `ustr.Substring(ustrLength - 1)`: extract the last character
- `ustr.Substring(1, ustr.Length - 2)`: extract all characters from the second to the second to last
- `ustr.Substring(0, 1)`: extract the first character

When concatenated in the order above you can see that the resulting string will start with the final character of the original string, followed by all characters from the second to the second to last, finally followed by the first character.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for explaining the miniature `if` statement line by line. Very useful

Answer (score 0):

Basically it says if the length is greater than 1 then execute this:

```
ustr.Substring(ustr.Length - 1) + ustr.Substring(1, ustr.Length - 2) + ustr.Substring(0, 1)
```

If not, return this string variable:

```
ustr
```

This is an example of Conditional Operator `"?:"`: [Microsoft Docs Conditional Operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Substring means you get specific range of string character. For examples, you can check [Substring Examples.](https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)